# Twitter Integration in iphone to read public tweets /HashTags without using login?

Tags: iphone, twitter

Hii People,

i m working on App which uses twitter api to fetch client public tweets,their Hashtag,

Currently i m using MGTwitterEngine which asks for userName,password to fetch tweets,

is any other ways we can able to fetch public tweets and their hashtag without login?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the public_timeline api does not require authentication so you could just use 
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/public_timeline.json?include_entities=true

I put a post on forrst.com as I've recently implemented something similiar in one of my projects:
http://forrst.com/posts/Grab_latest_Tweets_reusable_class-Ndz

Comment: worth noting from the recent announcements that twitter are deprecating the public api without oauth.