# How to embed a Twitter feed and/or hashtag in IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, hashtag, mgtwitterengine

I need basically just a table view that showed recent tweets from either a @username or a #hashtag in a tableviewcontroller. No requirements to post tweets or anything like that.

Currently I use `MGTwitterEngine` it is complicated and only fetches username related tweets not hastags.

I found this [tutorial](http://www.forcegrind.com/2011/07/26/ios-how-to-embed-a-twitter-feed-andor-hashtag-in-your-app/) but most of the codes is not explained and there is no source code.

Also find [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/312325/Making-a-simple-Twitter-app-using-iOS-5-Xcode-4-2?msg=4444279#xx4444279xx) but it seems `http://search.twitter.com/search?q=%23`+ #hashtag  returns `nil` data

Also saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860699/twitter-integration-in-iphone-to-read-public-tweets-hashtags-without-using-logi) edited code for ARC and used `http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23epicwinning+OR+%40charliesheen` link to fetch data

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@protocol latestTweetsDelegate
- (void)returnedArray:(NSArray*)tArray;
@end


@interface latestTweets : NSObject
{
    NSMutableData *responseData;
    NSMutableArray *resultsArray;
    id<latestTweetsDelegate> delegate;
}


@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *resultsArray;
@property (strong,nonatomic) id<latestTweetsDelegate> delegate;

- (id)initWithTwitterURL:(NSString *)twitterURL;

@end
#import "latestTweets.h"
#import "SBJson.h"

@implementation latestTweets
@synthesize resultsArray, delegate;

- (id)initWithTwitterURL:(NSString *)twitterURL
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        responseData = [NSMutableData data];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:twitterURL]];
        [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [responseData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {

    NSLog(@"Connection failed: %@", [error description]);
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSArray *newData = [responseString JSONValue];


    [self.delegate returnedArray:newData];
}

@end
```

I call

```
latestTweets *lt = [[latestTweets alloc] initWithTwitterURL:@"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23epicwinning+OR+%40charliesheen"];
lt.delegate = self;
```

Returns result array : `-[TwitterFeed returnedArray:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance`

Is there any simple tutorial or code sample to fetch both username and hashtag tweets at the same time?

or

Is there a  way to fetch also hashtags with `MGTwitterEngine` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to implement your own method below an example source code that works

Try this git

https://bitbucket.org/wave_1102/hdc2010-iphone/src

In your terminal `hg clone https://bitbucket.org/wave_1102/hdc2010-iphone` type and fetch git.

In `HDC2010ViewController` replace `win` with your hashtag

```
// search twitter for the HDC10 hashtag and add the tweets to our array
    [ tweetArray addObjectsFromArray:[ tweetFactory recentTweetsForHashTag:@"win" ] ];
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at [STTwitter](https://github.com/nst/STTwitter).

```
STTwitterAPI *twitter =
    [STTwitterAPI twitterAPIApplicationOnlyWithConsumerKey:@""
                                                   consumerSecret:@""];

[twitter verifyCredentialsWithSuccessBlock:^(NSString *bearerToken) {

    [twitter getSearchTweetsWithQuery:@"Snowden"
                         successBlock:^(NSDictionary *searchMetadata, NSArray *statuses) {
        // use the statuses here
    } errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
        // ...
    }];

} errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
    // ...
}];
```

Comment: Hi nst, how to implement paging for this twitter search API?

Comment: use the full method getSearchTweetsWithQuery: which includes the sinceID and maxID parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Twitter Kit to display a full timeline in your app (https://docs.fabric.io/ios/twitter/show-timelines.html).

```
class SearchTimelineViewController: TWTRTimelineViewController {

  convenience init() {
    let client = TWTRAPIClient()
    let dataSource = TWTRSearchTimelineDataSource(searchQuery: "#objc", APIClient: client)
     self.init(dataSource: dataSource)

     // Show Tweet actions
     self.showTweetActions = true
  }
 
}
```

[image]